# How to remove line breaks in particular column while exporting data in db2

Tags: unix, db2

I am trying to export data from a DB2 database to a text file Each column is surrounded by "double quotes" and separated by semicolon however there is one column that contains line breaks. Is there anyway so that I can remove line breaks and export as single line while exporting

Example
test.txt:

```
1."123","qweeerr","qqqqqq
2. rrrrr
3. hhhhhh","sdfsfs"
```

I need output like below in test.xt

```
1. "123","qweeerr","qqqqqq rrrrr hhhhhh","sdfsfs"
```

Comment: You have not explained *why* you want to alter the data, which is usually not necessary if you want to load/import/ingest the resulting-file into another Db2 table (c.f. CHARDEL, COLDEL options ).  But you can alter the SELECT statement of the export so that you use the TRANSLATE function around only that column-name with arguments to replace the newline by nothing, although the newline character may vary depending on the encoding of the source-table/column so care is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
mayankp@mayank:~/$ tr '\n' ' ' < test.txt
"123","qweeerr","qqqqqq rrrrr hhhhhh","sdfsfs"
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing all x'0D' and x'0A' characters to a space.
If you want to remove them, specify '' as the last parameter instead of ' '.

```
select translate(s, '', x'0d0a', ' ')
from table(values 'a'||x'0d'||x'0a'||'b', 'a'||x'0a'||'b') t(s);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ sed -z 's/\n"/"/g'  test.txt
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. A quick overview on how each part of that regex works can be very beneficial to people in the future when trying to replicate / alter the regex.